# how to add a new property to the existing type with d.ts in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

in my src/router.ts

```
export function resetRouter() {
    router.matcher = createRouter().matcher 
    // Property 'matcher' does not exist on type 'VueRouter'. Did you mean 'match'?
}
```

i create a src/router.d.ts and write some code:

```
import 'vue-router'

declare module 'vue-router' {
    class VueRouter {
        matcher: any
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work, the error still exist

here is node_modules/vue-router/index.d.ts file

```
export declare class VueRouter {
  constructor(options?: RouterOptions)

  app: Vue
  options: RouterOptions
  mode: RouterMode
  currentRoute: Route

  beforeEach(guard: NavigationGuard): Function
 ...
```

so how to fix this ?

Comment: Try `interface` instead of `class` in your declaration (on mobile now, will follow up when I get to a real computer)

Comment: Do you have a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates your issue? I'm almost sure you just need to change `class` to `interface` but I can't reproduce your problem because I don't have the right configuration for vue.  If you can set it up in something like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) or another web IDE I could verify. Otherwise maybe someone with vue expertise can help you. Good luck!

Comment: 'interface instead of class' is ok !
declare module 'vue-router/types/router' {
    interface VueRouter {
        matcher: any 
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), where you can add another declaration with the same name as an existing one, and the compiler will merge them into a single definition.  And, as you've seen, it is [disallowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges) to merge two `class` declarations together.

Luckily, you *are* allowed to merge an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) with the *instance side* of a `class` declaration:

```
// existing class declaration
class Foo {
  a: string = "a";
  b: string = "b";
}

// merge another property into the type named Foo
interface Foo {
  z: string
}

// test it out
const f = new Foo();
f.z = "hello"; // okay
console.log(f.z.toUpperCase()); // "HELLO"
```

---

Note that declaration merging doesn't have any effect at runtime, so if you merge an added property into the class *type*, you also need to write code to add the property at runtime also, otherwise you can hit runtime problems:

```
const g = new Foo();
g.z.toUpperCase(); // no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! g.z is undefined
```

All properties added to the instance side of classes should therefore either accept [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) (such as making them [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties)), or you need to modify the class itself to add the property, say, to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for the class:

```
// merge property into Foo type
interface Foo {
  z: string
}
// also add property to Foo class prototype
Foo.prototype.z = "defaultValue";

const h = new Foo();
console.log(h.z.toUpperCase()); // "DEFAULTVALUE"
h.z = "hello";
console.log(h.z.toUpperCase()); // "HELLO"
```

---

That means for your example you could write

```
import 'vue-router'

declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface VueRouter { // interface instead of class
    matcher: any 
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that your `VueRouter` class instances will not actually have a `matcher` property unless you add them somewhere.  Since [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) accepts `undefined` this isn't really a problem for the type system, but it might or might not behave as desired at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcgG4FcCmBaKEUzVBAWACgSATNAYwBsBDKNOECMlax5dLHPAuAbxJw4wAHa8AZrUqMAaugBKPfAKHCmtGJQAW+AFxxaogJ5w1AXxKXSNmrQDO9uADEIEVcWG0D9mFDEA5nAAvHAARLRhANxqAEY+foEh4bHRViQkYpLSjK7ugp5wAF4J-qIB6bYQor5wEsmiaADuLm4AFACUMcQSAHRFyWG61NQQ0XAA9BNwEADWtMYklNX2EOy9owFtfUW9MBAAqmBg+ADCDmidXZPTYQASAKIAMk8A8mEZxMs18EGhjS08p1un5TAVhAF+ntDsczhdgVY4JRNDo4G00B0PMJvqt1pt0ZipnBALwbgFKduCQgbAJwoUQUCRiNBkMzEayfPK9MDYfYwYwnfqDem0NgwWS0ajoNJVH5wbQNZqtCAIr4rNZoDYQLbaKH7I4nKDneyXDrXIlhAAiD2cAEEDk8ACqya1PA4PD7EbUDUJDNAjMbdHFqjVanUw-WG42m26PF7vT5AA)

Comment: how can i modify the property in VueRouter ? change 'app: Vue' to 'app: any'  
declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface VueRouter { 
    app: any
  }
}

Comment: You can't use declaration merging to *modify* a property that already exists; if you need a solution for that you might want to post a different question (assuming you can't find an existing question with a relevant answer).